# Installing Prolog via Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, prolog, installation, homebrew, swi-prolog

A colleague at university suggested I install swi-Prolog via Eclipse. I wish to install prolog in order to understand some code written in it, such as the code here: https://github.com/mwhite14850/dyc3g/tree/master/prolog

However, I saw that one can install swi-Prolog on the Mac terminal with Homebrew by typing `brew install swi-prolog` or `brew install swi-prolog --HEAD`? 
   My questions are these:

(1) What are the advantages of installing swimming-Prolog via Eclipse, as opposed to simply using Homebrew in the manner described?
(2) How does one install swi-Prolog via eclipse using home-brew?

Comment: I have no idea what "install via Eclipse" means, but I certainly always use brew or whatever the OS packaging system is if I can. I can't imagine it matters in the end.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns installing the language rather than programming in it

Comment: If you need help installing, you'll get a lot further on the [SWI-Prolog discourse group](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/) than here.

Comment: @Daniel Lyons I asked my question putting the tag 'install'. Usually you can ask questions about installation on this site. (just search through stack overflow)